# Android Custom Keyboard stuck When Swapping to/from Another Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard for Android that will store login credentials in a local database (plan is to encrypt the DB after the thing works flawlessly).

The keyboard has a basic layout with a KeyboardView at the bottom and a 'Switch Keyboard' button at the top-right corner.

Everything works fine except that when i click the switch button, things start to fail.

Scenario:

1) My keyboard is active and everything is fine. Keyboard visibility is managed by the system.

2) I click the switch button, my keyboard is closed and previously enabled keyboard is displayed.

3) Now i open the Keyboard Chooser through Notification Tray and re-enable my custom keyboard.

My keyboard is set as default, but there's no keyboard on the screen. when i touch the bottom half of screen area where keyboard appears, the characters are being typed (yes, my keyboard is there but is invisible!).

I press the Back key on my phone and the system doesn't close the keyboard and it's stuck there.

I press the Home key and the keyboard becomes visible for a few milliseconds, is closed by the system and i'm sent to the Home Screen.

I've tried waiting for the keyboard to appear, etc. and also tried the app on 3 other phones from different make. Also, i'm developing the app for Lollipop (API 21 and higher).

Here's the code:

1) InputMethodService:

```
   public class HomlesInputService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    CustomKeyboardView kv;
    Keyboard qwertyKeyboard, symbolKeyboard;
    Boolean caps;
    private String myPwd, myUid;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit;
    Boolean isPassword, isUid, uidFilled, pwdFilled;
    Vibrator vibrator;
    View keyboard;
    EditorInfo sEditorInfo;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    InputMethodManager imm;
    IBinder token;
    String defImeId;
    public static final int SYM_KEYBOARD = -10;
    public static final int GO_BUTTON = -4;
    public static final double GO_BUTTON_ASPECT_RATIO = 1.88;
    public static final double NEXT_BUTTON_ASPECT_RATIO = 1;


    public HomlesInputService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEdit = mPrefs.edit();

        //storing ime id in prefs
        String myId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
        mEdit.putString(Constants.MY_IME_ID, myId);
        mEdit.commit();

        imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        defImeId = mPrefs.getString(Constants.DEFAULT_KEYBOARD, null); //the id of previous IME stored in preferences (found correct in debugging)

        qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty_keyboard_layout);
        symbolKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbol_keyboard_layout);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DbConstants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DbConstants.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + DbConstants.APP_ID + "," + DbConstants.UID_VALUE + "," + DbConstants.PWD_VALUE + ")");


        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() { 

        keyboard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_custom_keyboard, null);

        ImageView ivRevertKeyboard = (ImageView) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.ivRevertKeyboard); //this button is used to switch to previous IME

        token = this.getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;

        if (defImeId != null) {
            ivRevertKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(Constants.VIBRATE_TIME_MEDIUM);
                    try {

                        imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(token, 0);
                        imm.setInputMethod(token, defImeId);

                    } catch (Throwable t) { // java.lang.NoSuchMethodError if API_level<11
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ivRevertKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        kv = (CustomKeyboardView) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

        kv.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

        caps = false;
        myPwd = "";
        myUid = "";
        isPassword = false;

        return keyboard;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) { 
        sEditorInfo = info;

        uidFilled = false;
        pwdFilled = false;


        if (info.inputType == 129) {
            isPassword = true;
        } else {
            isPassword = false;
        }

        CharSequence CHARbeforeCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(999, 0);
        CharSequence CHARafterCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextAfterCursor(999, 0);
        if (CHARbeforeCursor != null && CHARafterCursor != null) {
            String beforeCursor = CHARbeforeCursor.toString();
            String afterCursor = CHARafterCursor.toString();
            if (isPassword) {
                myPwd = beforeCursor + afterCursor;
            } else {
                myUid = beforeCursor + afterCursor;
            }
        }

        setGoButton();

    }


    private void setGoButton() {
        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = kv.getKeyboard().getKeys();
        Drawable dr;

        int rowHeight, goBtWidth = 0, nextBtWidth = 0;

        rowHeight = Utils.dpToPx(40, getApplicationContext());
        goBtWidth = Integer.parseInt("" + Math.round(rowHeight * GO_BUTTON_ASPECT_RATIO));
        nextBtWidth = Integer.parseInt("" + Math.round(rowHeight * NEXT_BUTTON_ASPECT_RATIO));

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            Keyboard.Key key = keys.get(i);
            int code = key.codes[0];
            if (code == GO_BUTTON) {
                if (isPassword) {
                    key.width = goBtWidth;
                    dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_save_and_go, getApplicationContext().getTheme());
                } else {
                    key.width = nextBtWidth;
                    dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_next, getApplicationContext().getTheme());
                }
                key.icon = dr;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        vibrator.vibrate(Constants.VIBRATE_TIME_SHORT);
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                break;
            case SYM_KEYBOARD:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                break;
            case 32:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
                break;
            default:
                kv.setPreviewEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] ints) {
        InputConnection conn = getCurrentInputConnection();
        uidFilled = mPrefs.getBoolean(Constants.UID_FILLED, false);
        pwdFilled = mPrefs.getBoolean(Constants.PWD_FILLED, false);
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                conn.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                if (isPassword) {
                    if (myPwd.length() > 0) {
                        String beforeCursor = conn.getTextBeforeCursor(myPwd.length(), 0).toString();
                        beforeCursor = beforeCursor.substring(0, beforeCursor.length());
                        String afterCursor = conn.getTextAfterCursor(myPwd.length(), 0).toString();
                        myPwd = beforeCursor + afterCursor;
                        if (uidFilled && pwdFilled) {
                            mEdit.putString(Constants.EDIT_NEW_PWD, myPwd);
                        } else {
                            mEdit.putString(Constants.NEW_PWD, myPwd);
                        }
                        mEdit.commit();
                        Log.d("##Pwd saved", "" + mPrefs.getString(Constants.NEW_PWD, ""));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (myUid.length() > 0) {
                        String beforeCursor = conn.getTextBeforeCursor(myUid.length(), 0).toString();
                        beforeCursor = beforeCursor.substring(0, beforeCursor.length());
                        String afterCursor = conn.getTextAfterCursor(myUid.length(), 0).toString();
                        myUid = beforeCursor + afterCursor;
                        if (uidFilled && pwdFilled) {
                            mEdit.putString(Constants.EDIT_NEW_UID, myUid);
                        } else {
                            mEdit.putString(Constants.NEW_UID, myUid);
                        }
                        mEdit.commit();
                        Log.d("##Uid saved", "" + mPrefs.getString(Constants.NEW_UID, ""));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                caps = !caps;
                kv.setShifted(caps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:

                switch (sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                        conn.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                        conn.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                        conn.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                        conn.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                        saveCredentialsToDb();
                        conn.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                        //triggers login
                        break;
                    default:
                        conn.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                        break;
                }

                break;
            case SYM_KEYBOARD:
                Keyboard currentKeyb = kv.getKeyboard();
                if (currentKeyb == symbolKeyboard) {
                    kv.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
                } else {
                    kv.setKeyboard(symbolKeyboard);
                }
                setGoButton();

                break;
            default:
                char code = (char) primaryCode;
                if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
                if (isPassword) {
                    myPwd = myPwd + code;
                    if (uidFilled && pwdFilled) {
                        mEdit.putString(Constants.EDIT_NEW_PWD, myPwd);
                    } else {
                        mEdit.putString(Constants.NEW_PWD, myPwd);
                    }
                    mEdit.commit();
                    Log.d("##Pwd saved", "" + mPrefs.getString(Constants.NEW_PWD, ""));
                } else {
                    myUid = myUid + code;
                    if (uidFilled && pwdFilled) {
                        mEdit.putString(Constants.EDIT_NEW_UID, myUid);
                    } else {
                        mEdit.putString(Constants.NEW_UID, myUid);
                    }
                    mEdit.commit();
                    Log.d("##Uid saved", "" + mPrefs.getString(Constants.NEW_UID, ""));
                }
                conn.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
        }

    }

    private void saveCredentialsToDb() {

        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DbConstants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String activityDbId = getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName;

        if (myUid == null || myUid.length() <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (myPwd == null || myPwd.length() <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if (activityDbId == null && activityDbId.length() <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get app ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Log.d("##Activity pkg name", "" + activityDbId);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DbConstants.APP_ID, activityDbId);
        cv.put(DbConstants.UID_VALUE, myUid);
        cv.put(DbConstants.PWD_VALUE, myPwd);
        if (uidFilled && pwdFilled) {
            String oldUid = mPrefs.getString(Constants.EDIT_OLD_UID, null);
            String oldPwd = mPrefs.getString(Constants.EDIT_OLD_PWD, null);
            if (oldUid != null && oldPwd != null) {
                if (oldUid.contentEquals(myUid) && oldPwd.contentEquals(myPwd)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unchanged values.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                db.update(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, cv, DbConstants.APP_ID + "=?" + " AND " + DbConstants.UID_VALUE + "=?", new String[]{activityDbId, oldUid});
                mEdit.remove(Constants.EDIT_OLD_UID);
                mEdit.remove(Constants.EDIT_NEW_UID);
                mEdit.remove(Constants.EDIT_NEW_PWD);
                mEdit.putBoolean(Constants.UID_FILLED, false);
                mEdit.putBoolean(Constants.PWD_FILLED, false);
                mEdit.commit();
                uidFilled = false;
                pwdFilled = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials edited!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Cursor cr2 = db.query(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, DbConstants.APP_ID + "=?" + " AND " + DbConstants.UID_VALUE + "=?", new String[]{activityDbId, myUid}, null, null, null);
            if (cr2.moveToNext()) {
                db.update(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, cv, DbConstants.APP_ID + "=?" + " AND " + DbConstants.UID_VALUE + "=?", new String[]{activityDbId, myUid});
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials edited!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                db.insert(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
                Log.d("Stored:" + activityDbId, myUid + "->" + myPwd);
                mEdit.remove(Constants.NEW_UID);
                mEdit.remove(Constants.NEW_PWD);
                mEdit.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials stored!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInput() {
        super.onFinishInput();
        Log.d("onFinishInput", "invoked");
    }


    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }

}
```

2) CustomKeyboardView:

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
    Context mContext;
    Boolean caps;

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        caps = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setShifted(boolean shifted) {
        super.setShifted(shifted);
        caps = shifted;
        invalidateAllKeys();
        return shifted;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
            Drawable dr = null;
            if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
                dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_backspace, mContext.getTheme());
                dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
                dr.draw(canvas);
            } else if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT) {
                dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyboard_shift, mContext.getTheme());
                dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
                dr.draw(canvas);
            } else if (key.codes[0] == 32) { //space bar
                int tenDp = Utils.dpToPx(10, mContext);
                int twoDp = Utils.dpToPx(2, mContext);
                dr = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
                dr.setBounds(key.x + twoDp, key.y + (tenDp), key.x + key.width - twoDp, key.y + key.height - (tenDp));
                dr.draw(canvas);
            }


            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            mPaint.setTextSize(Utils.dpToPx(18, mContext));
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            if (key.label != null) {
                String keyLabel = key.label.toString();
                if (caps) {
                    keyLabel = keyLabel.toUpperCase();
                }
                canvas.drawText(keyLabel, key.x + (key.width / 2),
                        key.y + (key.height / 2) + Utils.dpToPx(5, mContext), mPaint);
            } else if (key.icon != null) {
                key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
                key.icon.draw(canvas);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

3) R.layout.my_custom_keyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRevertKeyboard"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/keyboard_icon" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.prasad.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:keyPreviewHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@xml/keyboard_preview"
        android:shadowColor="@color/transparent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Expected behaviour: The keyboard should be displayed and hidden properly by the system after swapping multiple times with another keyboard.

Please let me know if you need additional details. Any clues will be appreciated.

Regards,

Prasad

Answer (score 0):

how is this?

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vibrator.vibrate(Constants.VIBRATE_TIME_MEDIUM);
        try {
//            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(token, 0);
//            imm.setInputMethod(token, defImeId);
                this.switchInputMethod(defImeId);

        } catch (Throwable t) { // java.lang.NoSuchMethodError if API_level<11
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: apparently the issue was too much processing in the IME's onDraw method and database calls in the IME. I had to put db calls on background thread and optimize the code in onDraw.